# Как сделать с обычных вкладок - вкладки accordion?

Tags: reactjs

Как сделать с вкладок код которых представлен ниже, вот такие вкладки(accordion) с классовыми компонентами и без хуков(hooks)?
http://i.piccy.info/i9/580b50486398c499c32df544d1d0cab1/1567521219/48098/1334636/1.jpg
Вкладки идут одна за другой и контент не видно пока не нажали на вкладку, а сам контент отдаляет другую вкладку вниз.

У меня есть код обычных вкладок :
https://jsfiddle.net/s2ze9pfk/ 
Но здесь вкладки обычные кроме того они функциональние и с хуками.

И сайт просит:
"Ссылки на jsfiddle.net должны сопровождаться кодом"
поэтому напишу кроме ссылки которая выше еще и React код:

```
const TabContent = ({ content }) => (
  <div className="accordion">
    <p>{content}</p>
  </div>
);

function Tabs({ items }) {

  const [active, setActive] = React.useState(0);


  const openTab = e => {
    setActive(+e.target.dataset.index);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <div className="tab">
        {items.map((n, i) => (
          <button

            key={i}
            className={`tablinks${i === active ? ' active' : ''}`}
            onClick={openTab}
            data-index={i}
          >
            {n.title}
          </button>
        ))}
      </div>
      {items[active] && <TabContent {...items[active]} />}
    </div>
  );
}


const items = [
  {
    title: 'First',
    content:
      '1. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.'
  },
  {
    title: 'Second',
    content:
      '2. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.'
  },
  {
    title: 'Third',
    content:
      '3. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.'
  }
];

ReactDOM.render(<Tabs items={items} />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот так будет выглядеть классовый компонент

```
const TabContent = ({content}) => (
    <div className="accordion">
        <p>{content}</p>
    </div>
);

class Tabs extends React.Components {

    state = {
        active: 0,
    }

    openTab = e => {
        this.setState({active: +e.target.dataset.index});
    };

    render() {
        const {items} = this.props;
        const {active} = this.state;
        return (
            <div>
                <div className="tab">
                    {items.map((n, i) => (
                        <button

                            key={i}
                            className={`tablinks${i === active ? ' active' : ''}`}
                            onClick={this.openTab}
                            data-index={i}
                        >
                            {n.title}
                        </button>
                    ))}
                </div>
                {items[active] && <TabContent {...items[active]} />}
            </div>
        );
    }
}


const items = [
    {
        title: 'First',
        content:
            '1. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.'
    },
    {
        title: 'Second',
        content:
            '2. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.'
    },
    {
        title: 'Third',
        content:
            '3. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.'
    }
];

ReactDOM.render(<Tabs items={items}/>, document.getElementById('app'));
```